# text replace using charcode in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

How do you replace text based on a charcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var charcode = 34; //example, put whatever here
var char = String.fromCharCode(charcode);

var string_to_edit = 'This is my string.';

var new string = string_to_edit.replace(char, 'whatever you are replacing with');
```

You may have to make that a pattern to use replace(), but I don't think so.

Comment: Note that strings are inmutable in Actionscript. So you can't really change a string. In this case, it means you have to re-assign the string returned by `replace` to `string_to_edit` (or any other variable, if needed).

Comment: my bad, fixed. was writing from the hip, hadn't checked it.

Comment: This is OK, as far as it goes, but it's not AS3. You're not casting and/or scoping variables, etc.